# How to select only specific properties of navigation property

Tags: entity-framework, linq

I've got a simplify entity structure like the following:

```
class MarkingTask{
    List<Task_Student> task_Students
}
 
class Task_Student{
    List<Task_Student_Marker> task_Student_Markers
}

class Task_Student_Marker{
    User marker
}
class User{
   string name;
   int age;
   int password;
}
```

I am doing an eager loading like the following:

```
   var taskList = context.markingTasks
                .Include(mt => mt.task_Students)
                .ThenInclude(ts => ts.task_Student_Markers)
                .ThenInclude(tsm => tsm.marker) //Here, only want to select marker.name 
                .ToList();
```

The question is where can I do a `select` clause on the navigation property to select a few columns of interest? For instance, for now, all of the properties of `User` are being selected, but I just want the `User.name`.

I looked up the MSDN, it seems the `select` clause is not supported inside `include` clause.
or I have to break it down into several statements.

Thanks for the tip

Comment: ‘doing an eager loading’ --- why do you think you're doing eager loading?

Comment: `Include` and `Select` are two mutually exclusive things. If you use `Select` - `Include` is ignored. Also `Include` cannot handle `Select` inside it's body.

Comment: Try to specify which result DTO is needed, then we can help in writing correct LINQ Query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Include` and `Select` are two mutually exclusive things that can not be set simultaneously on the navigation object. In my case, they are all being interpreted as `left Join`, but `Include` will select all the properties in the navigation object. I ended up doing a few nested `select` to target properties of interset

```
         var mts = context.markingTasks.Where(mt => mt.rubric.moduleConvenor.emailAddress == email && mt.task_Students.Count() != 0)
            .Select(mt => new {
                    mt.name, 
                    mt.moduleCode, 
                    students = mt.task_Students.Select(ts => new { 
                                                                    ts.student.name,
                                                                    ts.student.studentId, 
                                                                    markers = ts.task_Student_Markers.Select(tsm=>tsm.marker.userName).ToList()}).ToList()}).ToList();
```